# Return list of tuples given a positive integer using recursion on Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, tuples

I am trying to define a "pairs" function, which given a positive integer, returns a list of pairs of positive integers, with the first component of the pair less than or equal to the second component, the sum of which is equal to the given positive integer. For example:

pairs 7 = [(1,6),(2,5),(3,4)]
pairs 10 = [(1,9),(2,8),(3,7),(4,6),(5,5)]

I've managed to do this without using recursion:

```
pairs :: Integral a => a -> [(a, a)]    
pairs 1 = []   
pairs x   
  | x <= 0 = error "It is not positive"  
  | mod x 2 == 0 = zip (enumFromTo 1 (div x 2)) (enumFromThenTo (pred x) (pred(pred x)) (div x 2))  
  | otherwise = zip (enumFromTo 1 (div x 2)) (enumFromThenTo (pred x) (pred(pred x)) (succ(div x 2)))
```

And using recursion:

```
generateTupleList::  Integral a => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]  
generateTupleList[] = undefined  
generateTupleList((a,b):[])  
  | (a + 1) > (b - 1) = ((a,b):[])  
  | otherwise = [(a,b)] ++ generateTupleList(((a+1),(b-1)):[])

pairs:: Integral a => a -> [(a, a)]  
pairs 1 = []  
pairs x  
  | x <= 0 = error "It is not positive"  
  | otherwise = generateTupleList[(1,x-1)]
```

My question is the following, Is there any other way of doing this "pairs" function using recursion and without creating another sub-function (generateTupleList in my case)?

Comment: Are you in the same class as the person who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62627752/7509065)?

Comment: I don't know, the question was removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do this:

```hs
pairs :: Integral a => a -> [(a, a)]
pairs x = map (\y -> (y, x - y)) [1..x `div` 2]
```

In case you don't know, `[a..b]` is equivalent to `enumFromThenTo a b`, and wrapping a function in backticks makes it behave like an operator, so `` a `div` b `` is the same as `div a b`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! Is there any way to do it using stack recursion by calling the function "pairs" itself?